# CSS multiple images plus multiple properties

Tags: css

I'm using the standard comma-separated multiple image CSS like this:

```
background-image: url(image-one.png), url(image-two.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

However I need image-one.png to float and to be 85% width. Image-two.png does not get that styling.

How do I apply that float and width styling to just one of the images?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, as background images have no notion of floating.

Comment: When you apply a float, you're floating the element that has a background, not the background itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I think you are describing:

```
background: url(image-one.png) left 0 no-repeat 10px 100px/85% 400px,
            url(image-two.png) 5px 5px no-repeat 5px 5px/600px 400px;
```

I'm not sure the image and element size etc so you can ignore the px values and put in your own.